# How to map a JPA entity field to different entity types based on a condition?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA Entity "Food" with a field "idPtr" that I want to map to either a "Vegetable" Entity or a "Fruit" Entity depending on the value of the "code" field. Here's what I have so far:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "food")
public class Food {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "ptr_id")
    private Integer idPtr;

    // ...
}
```

I want to modify the "idPtr" field to be either an Vegetable or a Fruit entity, depending on the value of the code field, in order to have something like this :

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "food")
public class Food {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ptr_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Vegetable ptrVegetable;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ptr_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Fruit ptrFruit;

    // ...
}
```

The condition would be something like
if("VEG".equals(code))
then we would join this Food with the entity Vegetable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [Single Table inheritance strategy](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance). In this case, `Food` entity should have two inheritors. The first one joins `Vegetable` and the second one joins `Fruit`. Look at the code example below.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "food")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="code", 
  discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
class Food {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("VEG")
class VegetableFood extends Food {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ptr_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Vegetable ptrVegetable;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("FRUIT")
class FruitFood extends Food {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ptr_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Fruit ptrFruit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I managed to make this work. I had to turn the food class into an abstract one so that i could be using it into QueryDSL.

Comment: You're welcome. If my advice helps you, could you mark it as an answer, please?